# How to control two-way binding initial update direction

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

Every now and then I face a situation where I need to set a two-way binding on a property where it would be preferred that upon setting the binding the initial update will be performed in target-to-source direction and not source-to-target. That is, when the binding is set the source property value is updated so that it reflects the target property value, which stays unchanged.

Is such scenario possible? And if it is, how can it be accomplished?

Of course there are several workarounds, such as caching the target property value, setting the binding and then restoring the cached value, but I'm interested a direct answer rather than a workaround.

**Example**

Let's say we have a `TextBox` with `Text` property set to `"foo"`. Also, we have a view-model with `Name` property (of type `string`) set to `null`. Now what I want to achieve is to bind the `Text` property to the `Name` property while preserving the `"foo"` value. Important thing here is to avoid setting `Text` to `null` and then back to `"foo"` (for whatever reason, e.g. because clearing the `TextBox` causes other controls to clear as well).

Answer (score 0):

Then the best practice is 1) to read the existing value from the control (Clearly Xaml is not supposed to have data binding). 2) At "Load" event, the control needs to create and establish data binding by calling "SetBinding." 3) Finally get the binding expression for the control and update source with the value from 1).

All the code should be implemented in "View" code, not in "ViewModel."

e.g.) This code snippet is not tested, but has come from my head in the ball park.

```
private void Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArg arg)
{
...
   var text = textBox.Text;
   var binding = new Binding();
   ... binding property here

   textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
   textBox.Text = text;

   var expression = BindingExpression.GetBindingExpression(textBox, TextBox.TextProperty);
   expression.UpdateSource();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I am aware of this technique (I mentioned it in the question as a workaround), but it's not what I'm looking for. Also, I don't see the need to do it on `Loaded` event (it will work as well at any given time), and I think that retrieving the binding expression and calling `UpdateSource()` is reduntant (the source will be updated automatically when `Text` property is set).

Answer (score 0):

How about creating an Attached Property that can be used to any UIElement? This should address the universality requirement.

```
<TextBlock Text="foo" 
           GlobalAttachedProperty:Value="{Binding Path=A_ValueFromVM_OR_SomeWhereElse}"
           GlobalAttachedProperty:Property="Text"/>
```

The `Value` property just contain a callback to set the binding when there is a change. You can add some fancy routine that do this just once.

Then the `Property` is just a way to get the actual property for binding purposes. There are some other way to accomplish this but this is the more direct way.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the best option is to set a default value in your model class. This is the purpose of the view model.

Comment: The thing is that I want to preserve _current_ value, and not _default_ value. Also, this solution assumes usage of MVVM pattern, and moreover, that the model is "mine", which may as well not be true, e.g. the binding's source is explicitly set to some other _WPF_ control.

Comment: You mentioned that you have a view-model, so my assumption that you use MVVM wasn't correct?

Comment: Your view-model should have all default values set and should not rely on WPF as you can use it in other applications like universal apps etc. I don't understand why you don't want to follow this approach? Please give me the real example where you want to set such default value.

Comment: Indeed I mentioned a view-model, but only as an example. I have general technical question and I would like not to limit it to a particular design pattern. I know that for each instance of the problem there might exist a solution, but my interest is to know whether there exists a "universal" way of accomplishing the scenario described in the question. As for another example, let's say I'm developing a control library, where the end user supplies the binding which I then need to set on a layout related property for layout saving purposes. I have no knowledge whether there even exists a _VM_...